# Automatically selecting every other row in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to create a table where every other row is selected (for looks, mainly).

I'm also wondering if there's a way to change the selection color to black, instead of the default, which seems to be blue.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
public class Statistics {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new Statistics().construct();
    }

    public void construct() {
        frame = new JFrame("Statistics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(getComponents());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel getComponents() {
        contentPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());     
        String[] columnNames = { "Statistic name", "Statistic value" };
        Object[][] data = { { "Score", "0"}, {"Correct percentage", "100%" } };
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);       
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);        
        return contentPane;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. dont think that you _really_ want to achieve "striping" (aka: alternating row background color) by selection ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that easiest and confortable way for `JTable` would be to look for `prepareRenderer`, then there to override

```
if (isSelected) {
   setBackground(myTable.getBackground); // Color.white
} else {
   setBackground(whatever.Color);
}
```

sorry I can't resist, your code would be

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Statistics {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Statistic name", "Statistic value"};
    private Object[][] data = {{"Score", "0"}, {"Correct percentage", "100%"}};
    private JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    public Statistics() {
        frame = new JFrame("Statistics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(getComponents());
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getComponents() {
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));        
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return contentPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 See also [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).